# Gmaps set current position by Keywords error

Tags: c#, gmap.net

TRIED THIS CODE:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GeoCoderStatusCode status = gMapControl1.SetCurrentPositionByKeywords(textBox3.Text);
        if (status != GeoCoderStatusCode.G_GEO_SUCCESS)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Geocoder can't find: '" + textBox3.Text + "', reason: " + status.ToString(), "GMap.NET", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }

        else { gMapControl1.SetCurrentPositionByKeywords(textBox3.Text) };

    }
```

I only receive the message box error

Answer (score 0):

use the hot version, the stable version does not work with .NET 4, here:
https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/releases/view/73162

is the last of the page.